# What method is used to derive at the function to use in the squeeze theorem?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits

In every exam in the past $5$ years of Calculus A the question has popped up:
Use the squeeze theorem to evaluate the $\lim_{x\to n} f(x)$ where $f(x)$ took many forms from a normal algebraic equation to a trigonometric equation.

I understand most of the theory but how do you determine the function, let's say $g(x)$ to squeeze with? Is there a specific method? I would appreciate if anyone can give me some insight on this.

I did not put the specifics of $f(x)$ as that is not what I am struggling with.

Comment: There's not really any general method. It usually mostly involves some familiarity with common inequalities, generally bounding a complex term by a simpler one.

Comment: in other words it is what you know (experience) and nothing else?

Comment: There are some common things that will come up with enough practice, but generally, no, there's not much else. Taylor series can provide a good start (For transcendental functions), as can doing such simple things as changing powers of $x$ (For algebraic fractions) or adding/subtracting a function whose value at $n$ is zero. In the end, though, it just comes down to having some intuition (Gained through practice) for what will work in a given situation.

Comment: actually that is a good answer, I was really hoping that there would be a algebraic rule to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you'll use the squeeze thereom with trig functions:
$$-1 <= sin(x) <= 1$$
$$-1 <= cos(x) <= 1$$

Those are the most common.

Comment: You are right; most of them are and I have all the last exam papers for the last 5 years in front of me.